# How to combine similar tables effectively in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, union

I have an SQL problem I would be deeply grateful for any help because it would save me huge amounts of time and simplify so many of my queries.

Problem : My postgresql database contains multiple schemas, each corresponding to each of our clients. Each client has its own tables that are all structured the same way (client_1 has the same table names and field names as client_2). What I want to do is combine all client purchase data together in one big all clients table via SQL in a simpler way than my current method.

example of current query:

```
select field_1,
  field_2,
  'client_1' as client
from clientA.purchases
UNION ALL
select field_1,
  field_2,
  'client_2' as client
from clientB.purchases
UNION ALL
select field_1,
  field_2,
  'client_N' as client
from clientN.purchases
```

This becomes very impractical when there are many clients and I want to make changes later on, as I have to copy/paste N times. I would like to only have to write the contents of the SELECT once if possible. How can I achieve this?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: There is an implication here that perhaps you should just have a single table with a client column.  That being said, you could write a script which generates the union query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen is right. If you don't have a very strong good reason to have a separate schema for each client, you should just have a client_id column and stick with a single schema. Playing with several schema is sub-optimal.

Comment: I made the comment to my team leader a while ago, but apparently it's to keep our data practices safe and stay in line with a commitment we make to our clients (which is not to mix their data with other clients in certain cases which apply to this database). I could do with some help or pointers on the script because I'm a beginner using SQL

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to use a single table for all data, but if you want to stick with your current layout, you could use partitioning: create a partitioned table and add all the existing tables as partitions. That would require physically adding the `client` column to all tables, but it would greatly simplify your queries, in that you only have to query the partitioned table.

An alternative would be to create a view for all the `UNION ALL`s and only change that view if you add another client.